# File synchronization between c# application (.NET) and microsoft server

Tags: c#, .net, file, server, synchronization

I am currently writing a c# application that includes file synchronization so that files can be provided for other clients and used offline. I thought of using the Microsoft File Sync Framework (.NET) to take care about the synchronization itself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt763483

We do have a MS server 2016 that could be used as a file server by creating a public share, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it (referring to security). I was also thinking about using (s)FTP or WebDAV to provide the files in order to have a secure connection. Is there a best practice how to do file synchronization in c# applications over the internet using a microsoft server without implementing your own server application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WebDAV finally worked great for me.